# Elixir: Logger :console backend does not log metadata like application, module, file

Tags: elixir

I have logger configuration of an application in umbrella project as follows:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console],
  level: :debug,
  format: "\n$time $metadata[$level] $levelpad$message\n",
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line]
```

In a worker process, I have logged:

```
Logger.info("Connected to RabbitMQ.")
```

But it does not log any metadata like application, module or function.

```
21:40:05.590 [info]  Connected to RabbitMQ.
```

What is the proper way of logging metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to set config key with `:console`, using `config/3`. The following config displays metadata:

```
config :logger, :console,
  level: :debug,
  format: "\n$time $metadata[$level] $levelpad$message\n",
  metadata: [:application, :module, :function, :file, :line]
```

### Details:

The [Logger documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/logger/Logger.html) says:

> Here is an example of how to configure the :console backend in a config/config.exs file:
>
> ```
> config :logger, :console,
>   format: "\n$time $metadata[$level] $levelpad$message\n"
>   metadata: [:user_id]
> ```

The example above works with metadata.

However, there is another example in the documentation that adds `:console` in `backends` keyword list and do not set `:console` as config key. This does not show metadata for console.

> to configure the :backends and compile_time_purge_level options in a config/config.exs file:

```
config :logger,
  backends: [:console],
  compile_time_purge_level: :info
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but I have to say the documentation is not very clear